# Filter a list of strings which contains one or more strings from another list with Java 8 streams

Tags: java, regex, java-8, java-stream

I want to use the strings imputed in a TextField to filter a list. I am using a KeyReleased Event on the TextField to filter the list on every key. The piece of code below filters  the list when I type in a word, but when I press space and start typing another word the list gets empty. I am a bit new to streams. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

---

```
private ObservableList<Products_Data> productList;
@FXML       
private JFXTextField searchField;
@FXML       
private TableView<Products_Data> productTable;
@FXML
void searchKeyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
    String searchText = searchField.getText();
    List<String> searchableWords = Arrays.asList(searchText.toLowerCase().trim().split("\\s+"));
    List<Products_Data> filteredList =  searchableWords.stream()
        .flatMap(i ->productList.stream()
        .filter(j -> j.getPartDesc().toLowerCase().contains(i)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    ObservableList<Products_Data> productFilteredList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(filteredList);
    productTable.setItems(productFilteredList);
}

----------
public class Products_Data {
    private final StringProperty partDesc = new (this,"PartDesc",null);

    public Products_Data() {}

    public final StringProperty getPartDescProperty() {return partDesc;}
    public final String getPartDesc(){return partDesc.get();}
    public final void setPartDesc(String partDesc) {     
        getPartDescProperty().set(partDesc);
    }

}
```

Comment: try testing what you get after `Arrays.asList(searchText.toLowerCase().trim().split("\\s+"));` using your input and further those attributes satisfy `<word>.getPartDesc().toLowerCase().contains(i)` as well?

Comment: What does `new (this,"PartDesc",null)` do? This can’t be your working code. And why do you wrap the text returned by `searchField.getText()` with `String.valueOf(…)`. The way you’ve written the stream code, you can have multiple occurrences of the same item. Can, whatever `productTable` is, handle such a case?

Comment: If the searchable set is small (and distinct), then I would personally make a `HashSet` of the input words, and a `LinkedHashSet` of your searchable words. Then remove the input from a copy of the searchable set. Less memory efficient, but should be quicker to compute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can’t see a fundamental problem in your Stream code. The way, you’ve written it, is not very efficient and it allows elements matching multiple words to occur multiple times in the result list. Perhaps, the UI you’re setting the result on can’t handle this.

I’d create a single filter out of the entered text, which will match if any of the words appears in the element, using a case insensitive matching instead of repeatedly converting every string to lowercase. E.g. with a utility method like this:

```
static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile("\\s+");

public static <T> Predicate<T> getFilter(Function<? super T, String> f, String words) {
    String regex = SPACE.splitAsStream(words)
        .map(Pattern::quote).collect(Collectors.joining("|"));
    Predicate<String> sp = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).asPredicate();
    return t -> sp.test(f.apply(t));
}
```

which can be used as

```
List<Products_Data> filteredList = productList.stream()
    .filter(getFilter(Products_Data::getPartDesc, searchField.getText()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

The core of your matching should be like this:

```
productList.stream().filter(
    product -> searchableWords.stream().allMatch(
        searchWord -> product.getPartDesc().toLowerCase().contains(searchWord)
    )
)
```