# java stream list of filters

Tags: java, filter, java-stream

Let's say I've got a list of Strings and I want to filter them by the list of filtering Strings. 
For the list which consists of:
"abcd", "xcfg", "dfbf"

I would precise list of filtering Strings:
"a", "b", and after something like filter(i->i.contains(filterStrings) I would like to receive list of "abcd", "dfbf",
And for a list of filtering Strings:
"c", "f" I would like to reveive list of "xcfg" and "dfbf".

```
List<String> filteredStrings = filteredStrings.stream()
            .filter(i -> i.contains("c") || i.contains("f")) //i want to pass a list of filters here
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is there an other way of doing this instead of expanding body of lambda expression and writing a function with a flag which will check every filter?

Comment: By the way please correct me if I am wrong, I'd assumed the second output should also include `abcd` for the presence of `c`?

Comment: @nullpointer yup, you’re right

Answer (score 5):

You should instead be performing a `anyMatch` over the list to match from:

```
List<String> input = Arrays.asList("abcd", "xcfg", "dfbf"); // your input list
Set<String> match = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("c", "f")); // to match from
List<String> filteredStrings = input.stream()
        .filter(o -> match.stream().anyMatch(o::contains))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `List`, that has an arbitrary number of filters

```
List<Predicate<String>> filterList = new ArrayList<>();
Predicate<String> containsCPredicate = s -> s.contains("c");
filterList.add(containsCPredicate);
filterList.add(s -> s.contains("f"));
...
```

You can then `reduce` the list of these filters into one, combining them:

```
filterList.stream().reduce(i -> true, Predicate::and)
```

when applying them on your stream pipeline, like

```
List<String> filteredStrings = strings.stream()
        .filter(filterList.stream().reduce(i -> true, Predicate::and))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The initial `i -> true` `Predicate` is the identity, the `reduce` operation needs as the first parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your `contains` with a simple regex :

```
.filter(i -> i.matches(".*[cf].*")) // to check just one character
```

or :

```
.filter(i -> i.matches(".*(c|f).*")) // or if you have a words
```

Answer (score 1):

A filter can be represented as a `Predicate`. In your case a `Predicate<String>`. So, a list of filter can be stored in a `List<Predicate<String>>`.

Now, if you want to apply such a list on each element of your `Stream`:

```
List<String> filteredStrings = input.stream()
                                    .filter(i -> filterList.stream().anyMatch(f -> f.test(i))) 
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

To complete the example:

```
List<String> input = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList ("abcd", "xcfg", "dfbf","erk"));
List<Predicate<String>> filterList = new ArrayList<>();
filterList.add (i -> i.contains("c"));
filterList.add (i -> i.contains("f"));
List<String> filteredStrings = input.stream()
                                    .filter(i -> filterList.stream().anyMatch(f -> f.test(i))) 
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println (filteredStrings);
```

Output:

```
[abcd, xcfg, dfbf]
```

Comment: This requires to create a `List<Predicate>` with each `Predicate` checking against one of the filter elements. @nullpointer's answer is preferrable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Pattern`:

```
static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("c|f");
```

And then check if a string matches said pattern.

```
List<String> strings = filteredStrings.stream()
    .filter(s -> pattern.matcher(s).find())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

That `pattern` can of course be computed by a given input:

```
public static Pattern compute(String... words) {
    StringBuilder pattern = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i++) {
       pattern.append(words[i]);
       if(i != 0) {
           pattern.append('|');
       }
    }
    return Pattern.compile(pattern);
}
```

Which could then be called like this:

```
Pattern patten = compute("some", "words", "hello", "world");
```

Which would result in a regex:

```
some|words|hello|world
```

Comment: You should keep in mind that for unknown input, you can not preclude that the words contain characters with special meaning to the regex engine. On the other hand, you can construct the regex using the Stream API as simple as `Arrays.stream(words) .map(Pattern::quote) .collect(Collectors.joining("|"))`, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54711540/2711488). If you are sure that the words do not contain special characters, you can use the even simpler `String.join("|", words)`. No need to deal with a `StringBuilder` in the application code…

Comment: …and instead of `.filter(s -> pattern.matcher(s).find())` you can simply use `.filter(pattern.asPredicate())`